# Drop down menu does not work properly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a triple drop down menu and when I select an option for first drop down, based on that I get the values populated in the second drop down but these values in the second drop down do not clear even though I change the change the option of my first drop down. I am facing this problem with Chrome. In Firefox it works fine. Could some one tell me how to clear the previous selection contents. I have pasted my code in the pastebin

http://paste.flingbits.com/m05ef5d2

Could any one please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

@Cutekate: Try changing `onClick` in all your `<select>`'s to `onChange`.

**Update:**

*JavaScript* (save this to `xhr.js`):

```
var xhr;

function countySelect(q) {
    if (q != "Select State") {
        xhr = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xhr == null) {
            document.write("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP");
            return;
        }
        var strURL = "findCounty.php?state=" + q + "&sid=" + Math.random();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = countyStateChanged;
        xhr.open("GET", strURL, true);
        xhr.send(null); 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("county").options.selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("genus").options.selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("csv").innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function genusSelect(q) {
    if (q != "Select County") {
        xhr = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xhr == null) {
            document.write("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP");
            return;
        }
        var strURL = "findGenus.php?county=" + q + "&sid=" + Math.random();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = genusStateChanged;
        xhr.open("GET", strURL, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("genus").options.selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById("csv").innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function dataSelect(q) {
    if (q != "Select Genus") {
        xhr = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xhr == null) {
            document.write("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP");
            return;
        }
        var strURL = "getData.php?genus=" + q + "&sid=" + Math.random();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = dataStateChanged;
        xhr.open("GET", strURL, true);
        xhr.send(null); 
    }
}

function countyStateChanged() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("countydiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}

function genusStateChanged() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
        document.getElementById("genusdiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}

function dataStateChanged() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
        document.getElementById("csv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    var xhr = null;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

*HTML*:

```
<!-- place above <form> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="xhr.js"></script>

<!-- rest of code... -->

    <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>
            <select id="state" name="state" onchange="countySelect(this.value)">
                <option value="Select State">Select State</option>
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>County</td>
        <td>
            <div id="countydiv">
                <select id="county" name="county" onchange="genusSelect(this.value)">
                    <option value="Select County">Select County</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Genus</td>
        <td>
            <div id="genusdiv">
                <select id="genus" name="genus" onchange="dataSelect(this.value)">
                    <option value="Select Genus">Select Genus</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

<!-- rest of code... -->

<div id="csv">
    <!-- output of dataSelect will be displayed here -->
</div>
```

Comment: It did work :) but in IE it is not working. It does not show my options in the second drop down menu at all. I tried changing it in many values but it is not working. Could you help me please???

Comment: @Cutekate: Please see my updated answer above, I hope it'll help. :-)